# mysql update another table using a trigger

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

I need to update the "video_upload" table after a row is inserted into the "video_ratings" table. Before do that I need to get the count of RATINGS column and then should do the update using that value. The required logic is below mentioned.

1. take the count of all 0s from video_ratings and update video_upload's RATE_BAD column.
2. take the count of all 1s from video_ratings and update video_upload's RATE_AVERAGE column.
3. take the count of all 2s from video_ratings and update video_upload's RATE_GOOD column.
4. take the count of all 3s from video_ratings and update video_upload's RATE_BEST column.

The video_upload table

```
  CREATE TABLE `video_upload` (
  `ID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `USER_ID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `VIDEO_NAME` varchar(75) COLLATE utf32_sinhala_ci NOT NULL,
  `VIDEO_URL` varchar(100) COLLATE utf32_sinhala_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `PIC1_URL` varchar(100) COLLATE utf32_sinhala_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `PIC2_URL` varchar(100) COLLATE utf32_sinhala_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `PIC3_URL` varchar(100) COLLATE utf32_sinhala_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `ATT_URL` varchar(100) COLLATE utf32_sinhala_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `TYPE` varchar(7) COLLATE utf32_sinhala_ci NOT NULL,
  `DESCRIPTION` varchar(2000) COLLATE utf32_sinhala_ci NOT NULL,
  `IsAPPROVED` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `RATE_BAD` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `RATE_AVERAGE` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `RATE_GOOD` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `RATE_BEST` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `UPLOADED_ON` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `UPDATED_ON` timestamp NOT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf32 COLLATE=utf32_sinhala_ci;
```

The video_ratings table

```
    CREATE TABLE `video_ratings` (
  `VID_ID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `STU_ID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `RATINGS` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `RATED_ON` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `UPDATED_ON` timestamp NOT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf32 COLLATE=utf32_sinhala_ci;
```

I'm planing to do this using trigger. I've also found some mysql trigger code from the Internet.

```
//Rating count trigger
create trigger rate_count_update
after insert on video_ratings for each row begin
DECLARE updatecount INT;
  set updatecount = ( select count(RATINGS) AS TOTAL from video_ratings where RATINGS='0' AND RATINGS='1' AND RATINGS='2' AND RATINGS='3' );
  if updatecount=4
    then
      update video_upload set RATE=TOTAL;
  end if;
end//
```

But I was unable modify it according my requirement. Please help on this.

Comment: You should know that is not how this site works. You should insist with those triggers examples and come back with an specific error.

Comment: Hi @RubioRic , sorry my bad. I've updated the question. Please refer.

Comment: I would expect to see OLD. or NEW. values in an update trigger.

Comment: Both of these tables deserve to have a PRIMARY KEY defined. And it also looks like `VID_ID` in `video_ratings` is a foreign key reference to `ID` column in `video_upload`.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of notes...

I can positively guarantee that there will be NO rows that satisfy the conditions

```
  FROM video_ratings
 WHERE RATINGS='0' 
   AND RATINGS='1'
   AND RATINGS='2'
```

Think about it.  If one of those conditions (comparisons) evaluates to TRUE, then the other comparisons are going to evaluate to FALSE, and

```
  TRUE  AND  FALSE  AND  FALSE
```

is going to evaluate to FALSE.

So the COUNT() aggregate on that statement is going to evaluate to 0.

---

On this UPDATE statement,

```
update video_upload set RATE=TOTAL;
```

it that's successful, that is going to update *every* row in the video_upload table. Seems like we would only want to update *one* row on the video_upload table, the row that has an `ID` value that matches the `VID_ID` of the row we just inserted into the `videos_ratings` table.

We can get the value of the `VID_ID` column of the row we just inserted by referencing

```
 NEW.VID_ID
```

in the trigger body. We probably want an update statement that looks something like this:

```
UPDATE video_upload v
   SET ...
 WHERE v.ID = NEW.VID_ID ;
```

If we want to assign values to the `RATE_BAD`, `RATE_AVERAGE`, `RATE_GOOD`  and `RATE_BEST` columns, we need the SET clause to reference those columns ...

```
UPDATE video_upload v
   SET v.RATE_BAD      = some_expr 
     , v.RATE_AVERAGE  = another_expr
     , v.RATE_GOOD     = expr_for_good
     , v.RATE_BEST     = expr_for_best
 WHERE v.ID = NEW.VID_ID ;
```

---

Maybe we wanted to do something like this, to get a count of the ratings and store those counts in local variables so we can reference those later in the trigger.

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(r.RATINGS='0'),0) AS cnt_r0
     , IFNULL(SUM(r.RATINGS='1'),0) AS cnt_r1 
     , IFNULL(SUM(r.RATINGS='2'),0) AS cnt_r2 
     , IFNULL(SUM(r.RATINGS='3'),0) AS cnt_r3 
  FROM video_ratings r 
 WHERE r.VID_ID = NEW.VID_ID
   INTO li_cnt_r0
      , li_cnt_r1
      , li_cnt_r2
      , li_cnt_r3
;
```

---

**followup**

I recommend this pattern for trigger names:  `table_name` + `_suffix`

where `_suffix` is one of '_ad', '_ai', '_au', '_bd', '_bi', '_bu' (for after/before delete/insert/update)

Following this naming convention avoids naming collisions, and when we are looking for triggers on table, we will know where to find them.  By listing the triggers in alphabetic order, all of the triggers for a given table will be grouped together by table_name (mostly). (The edge case, where we have potential for some intermingling is a table name that starts with the name of another table, followed by _a.. or _b..)

(In early development, when you have two tables and half a dozen triggers, the advantage of a such a naming convention isn't obvious. But it becomes readily apparent when the database contains a multitude of tables and triggers.)

Also note that MySQL supports only a single trigger for each of BEFORE/AFTER INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE on a given table.

Use local variables in favor of user-defined variables, unless there is a specific reason for using a user-defined variable.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS video_ratings_ad$$

CREATE TRIGGER video_ratings_ad
AFTER DELETE ON video_ratings
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   -- declare local variables
   DECLARE li_cnt_r0  BIGINT;
   DECLARE li_cnt_r1  BIGINT;
   DECLARE li_cnt_r2  BIGINT;
   DECLARE li_cnt_r3  BIGINT;
   -- get counts of ratings for specific VID_ID
   -- and store counts in local variables 
   SELECT IFNULL(SUM(r.RATINGS='0'),0) AS cnt_r0
        , IFNULL(SUM(r.RATINGS='1'),0) AS cnt_r1
        , IFNULL(SUM(r.RATINGS='2'),0) AS cnt_r2
        , IFNULL(SUM(r.RATINGS='3'),0) AS cnt_r3
     FROM video_ratings r
    WHERE r.VID_ID = OLD.VID_ID
     INTO li_cnt_r0
        , li_cnt_r1
        , li_cnt_r2
        , li_cnt_r3
   ;
   -- update target table with rating counts from local variables
   UPDATE video_upload t
      SET t.RATE_BAD      = li_cnt_r0
        , v.RATE_AVERAGE  = li_cnt_r1
        , v.RATE_GOOD     = li_cnt_r2
        , v.RATE_BEST     = li_cnt_r3
    WHERE t.ID = OLD.VID_ID
   ;
END$$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS video_ratings_ai$$

CREATE TRIGGER video_ratings_ai
AFTER UPDATE ON video_ratings
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   -- declare local variables
   DECLARE li_cnt_r0  BIGINT;
   DECLARE li_cnt_r1  BIGINT;
   DECLARE li_cnt_r2  BIGINT;
   DECLARE li_cnt_r3  BIGINT;
   -- get counts of ratings for specific VID_ID
   -- and store counts in local variables 
   SELECT IFNULL(SUM(r.RATINGS='0'),0) AS cnt_r0
        , IFNULL(SUM(r.RATINGS='1'),0) AS cnt_r1
        , IFNULL(SUM(r.RATINGS='2'),0) AS cnt_r2
        , IFNULL(SUM(r.RATINGS='3'),0) AS cnt_r3
     FROM video_ratings r
    WHERE r.VID_ID = NEW.VID_ID
     INTO li_cnt_r0
        , li_cnt_r1
        , li_cnt_r2
        , li_cnt_r3
   ;
   -- update target table with rating counts from local variables
   UPDATE video_upload t
      SET t.RATE_BAD      = li_cnt_r0
        , v.RATE_AVERAGE  = li_cnt_r1
        , v.RATE_GOOD     = li_cnt_r2
        , v.RATE_BEST     = li_cnt_r3
    WHERE t.ID = NEW.VID_ID
   ;
END$$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS video_ratings_au$$

CREATE TRIGGER video_ratings_au
AFTER UPDATE ON video_ratings
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   -- declare local variables
   DECLARE li_cnt_r0  BIGINT;
   DECLARE li_cnt_r1  BIGINT;
   DECLARE li_cnt_r2  BIGINT;
   DECLARE li_cnt_r3  BIGINT;
   IF( OLD.RATINGS <=> NEW.RATINGS 
   -- if VID_ID and RATINGS is not changed, we can skip getting counts
   IF( NEW.VID_ID <=> OLD.VID_ID AND NEW.RATINGS <=> OLD.RATINGS )
   THEN BEGIN END
   ELSE
      -- get counts of ratings for OLD.VID_ID
      -- and store counts in local variables
      SELECT IFNULL(SUM(r.RATINGS='0'),0) AS cnt_r0
           , IFNULL(SUM(r.RATINGS='1'),0) AS cnt_r1
           , IFNULL(SUM(r.RATINGS='2'),0) AS cnt_r2
           , IFNULL(SUM(r.RATINGS='3'),0) AS cnt_r3
        FROM video_ratings r
       WHERE r.VID_ID = OLD.VID_ID
        INTO li_cnt_r0
           , li_cnt_r1
           , li_cnt_r2
           , li_cnt_r3
      ;
      -- update target table with rating counts from local variables
      UPDATE video_upload t
         SET t.RATE_BAD      = li_cnt_r0
           , v.RATE_AVERAGE  = li_cnt_r1
           , v.RATE_GOOD     = li_cnt_r2
           , v.RATE_BEST     = li_cnt_r3
       WHERE t.ID = OLD.VID_ID
      ;
      IF( NEW.VID_ID <=> OLD.VID_ID )
      THEN BEGIN END
      ELSE
         -- get counts of ratings for specific VID_ID
         -- and store counts in local variables 
         SELECT IFNULL(SUM(r.RATINGS='0'),0) AS cnt_r0
              , IFNULL(SUM(r.RATINGS='1'),0) AS cnt_r1
              , IFNULL(SUM(r.RATINGS='2'),0) AS cnt_r2
              , IFNULL(SUM(r.RATINGS='3'),0) AS cnt_r3
           FROM video_ratings r
          WHERE r.VID_ID = NEW.VID_ID
           INTO li_cnt_r0
              , li_cnt_r1
              , li_cnt_r2
              , li_cnt_r3
         ;
         -- update target table with rating counts from local variables
         UPDATE video_upload t
            SET t.RATE_BAD      = li_cnt_r0
              , v.RATE_AVERAGE  = li_cnt_r1
              , v.RATE_GOOD     = li_cnt_r2
              , v.RATE_BEST     = li_cnt_r3
          WHERE t.ID = NEW.VID_ID
         ;
      END IF;
   END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Hi @spencer7593 , I've modifed the trigger as below mentioned but it gives me "Unknown system variable 'updatecount' " error when run the trigger. Colud you please help me. ~~

create trigger after_videor_update
before update on video_ratings
for each row
begin
 set updatecount = (select count(RATINGS) AS BAD_TOTAL from video_ratings where RATINGS='0');
 update video_upload
 SET RATE_BAD = updatecount ,
 where USER_ID = NEW.STU_ID AND ID = NEW.VID_ID; 
end ~~

Comment: Looks to me like `updatecount` isn't declared as a local variable. But why do a `SET` statement when we can do a `SELECT ... INTO` ?And why are we not getting the counts of all four ratings in one fell swoop? And why not update all four columns in `video_upload` with one statement execution?  Why are we not qualifying column references? And why are we including a condition to match `STU_ID` to `USER_ID` ... isn't `STU_ID` the user that is giving the rating, and don't we expect that to be different than the user that uploaded a video? Don't we want an AFTER trigger not a BEFORE trigger?

Comment: For the moment can you just help me with single rate trigger. After some modifications I've successfully saved the trigger bt it din't give me the expected results. any advises plz.
~~DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER after_videor_update 
    AFTER UPDATE ON video_ratings
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    SET `@updatecount` = (select count(RATINGS) AS BAD_TOTAL from video_ratings where RATINGS='0');
 update video_upload
 SET RATE_BAD =` @updatecount`
 where USER_ID = NEW.STU_ID AND ID = NEW.VID_ID;
END$$
DELIMITER ;~~